# Entity Framework Time Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having issues with inserting time into my database using Entity Framework.

Background: I am using a PC on UTC time to build this application. Once built I will deploy it on a server which is UTC + 1. The database it connects to is also on a server which is UTC + 1.

So when I run locally onto my PC I put in a time such as 9am and it saves in the database as 10am. This is as expected.

When I run on the server I put in a time of 9am and it saves in the database as 11am. This is not what i expected as it should have an hours difference not 2.

Can anyone assist with this. My current code is:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime Start = Convert.ToDateTime("27/04/2015 08:00");
        DateTime End = Convert.ToDateTime("27/04/2015 16:00");


        // generate a schedule
        ASML_ScheduleHeader schedule = new ASML_ScheduleHeader(); 
        schedule.ScheduleId = Guid.NewGuid();

        TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;     
        schedule.StartTime = localZone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(Start, DateTimeKind.Utc));
        schedule.EndTime = localZone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(End, DateTimeKind.Utc));           


        using (CIC40PrimaryEntities _context = new CIC40PrimaryEntities())
        {
            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Adding Header");
                _context.ASML_ScheduleHeader.Add(schedule);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Schedule added");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Schedule not added");
            }

            Console.Read();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: why not using UTC time for all?

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using UTC throughout, You can always convert the DateTime to local time in the presentation layer.

Therefore I would store it like;

```
schedule.StartTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(Start, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

It would help if you could give us some more explicit results, maybe some test cases :)

Comment: I have tried this however it still puts the incorrect time in. It just puts the time as 8am in the database when it should be 9am. My code is: 
                schedule.StartTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime Start = Convert.ToDateTime("29/04/2015 08:00"), DateTimeKind.Utc);.